# Is there a term for two differently phrased sentences with the same meaning?

Tags: synonyms, semantics

Is there a term that describes the relationship between different sentences with the same meaning, in the way "synonym" describes the relationship between different words with the same meaning?

For example:

> He's heavier than I am.

and

> He weighs more than I do.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I haven't thought of an answer yet, but in musing on it, it occurs to me that this phenomenon in music would be called "variations on a theme."

Comment: How about simply "paraphrase"?

Comment: @jubobs a paraphrase does not need to have the exact same meaning it can rephrase the meaning in a given context Ie in "`The signal was red`, that is, `the train was not allowed to proceed`" the latter highlighted sentence is paraphrasing the former (source: wikipedia)

Comment: Ok. After some research on Google, I found that the developmental-psychology literature uses the term *synonymous sentences*. Would that suit you?

Comment: I would say that the sentences "have equivalent meanings."

Comment: Well, no, that really isn't a paraphrase. A paraphrase is a restatement of the same sentence, clause, phrase, or other word cluster, in other terms or words, usually for the purpose of clarity and/or brevity. "The train was stopped" is a paraphrase of "the train was not allowed to proceed." Between "the signal was red" and "the train was not allowed to proceed," however, not only is there not even one single element of paraphrase, there is not even any NECESSARY connection. Wikipedia can be right, but also can be VERY wrong.

Comment: And therefore, by the way, @Jubobs is correct: Two differently phrased sentences with the same meaning are paraphrases of one another.

Comment: @Rune FS: You didn't copy the entire "paraphrasing" from the Wikipedia article. I wouldn't consider the bit you *have* copied to be a credible example of a "paraphrase". The full original says ["**The signal was red**" might be paraphrased as "The train was not allowed to pass **because the signal was red**"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraphrase). It has to have **exactly** the same meaning, or it's an *expansion*, not a *paraphrase*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The meaning does not have to be exactly the same between paraphrases. Another example would be (from yourdictionary) `Her life spanned years of incredible change for women.`paraphrased as `Mary lived through an era of liberating reform for women.` If you had only the first sentence would you be able to answer "What's her name?"

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg you are of course right that two sentences with the same meaning are paraphrases of each other but I'm looking for a more narrow term. I.e. `Her life spanned years of incredible change for women.`
`Mary lived through an era of liberating reform for women.` are paraphrases however they do not convey the same information. (The latter lets us know her name)

Comment: No, really, you must see this: The TWO ESSENTIAL ELEMENTS of a paraphrase are that THE SAME MEANING is conveyed AND that the WORDING is different. This is what DEFINES a paraphrase. This is WHAT IT IS. There is nothing else that it is or can be. Any statement that does not convey the same information as another CANNOT POSSIBLY BE A PARAPHRASE of the other. "Scarlet banks of clouds scudded across the sky," can be paraphrased as "red clouds moved overhead," but NOT as "he looked at weather patterns that he liked." THAT would be a different statement entirely.

Comment: "The signal was red" MIGHT IMPLY that "the train was not allowed to pass," but the two statements are NOT paraphrases. Their only possible connection is IMPLICATION, not rephrasing. A paraphrase is NOT an implication. It is an IDENTICAL statement IN DIFFERENT WORDS.

Comment: @ Rune FS: What John said. It's meaningless to say your "Mary" example is a "paraphrase" if you're postulating that the "she" version might be said in a context where *we don't know who's being spoken of*. If that were the case, the listener would be prompted to ask *"**Whose** life?"* - what you call a "paraphrase" there is actually what I say is an "expansion", in that it provides additional information that wasn't in the original, and couldn't be derived from it if you didn't know the context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but I'm not implying that but that doesn't change the fact that the two sentences convey the same meaning though not the same information. (and giving a context are paraphrases of each other)

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg by definition the meaning must be the same of course. But since information is a stricter term than meaning your expansion of the definition, stating that if the meaning is the same so must the information be is incorrect (the reverse is of course true) and the difference between meaning and definition is the detail I'm missing in paraphrase.

Comment: Okay, well, I would try to respond to this, but I haven't the faintest idea what you're saying. Paraphrasing is not a debatable concept, nor a subtle one. Have you noticed that everyone who has bothered to put in a comment here appears to agree with me (especially @FumbleFingers, one of the most knowledgeable and experienced users of this site)? That should tell you something.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg I donøt know if you've noticed that I haven't debatted paraphrasing just noted that I was looking for a stricter term but thatnks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Exactly as Jubobs said (cannot upvote your comment for some reason), from Webster definition of **paraphrase**:

> A restatement of a text, passage, or work giving the meaning in another form.
>
> Synonyms: rephrasing, restatement, restating, rewording

Comment: A paraphrase can vary too much from the original in the context of what I'm looking for. E.g. `Her life spanned years of incredible change for women.` can be paraphrased: `Mary lived through an era of liberating reform for women.` (source yourdictionary). The latter has some information of the former didn't though they still convey the same point. I'm looking for a term that describes the case where information is not lost between the two sentences

Comment: @rune fs Use one of the synonyms then: "rewording". The first and original meaning of rewording is to repeat in exactly the same words, only the second definition introduce the idea of "altering the wording of". It's as close to "synonym" as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

If one statement comes first, and you write it differently to produce the second, it can be called a *restatement*.

> **Restatement** *noun*
>   An act of stating something again or differently, especially more clearly or convincingly
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/restatement)

If the statements are not derived from each other, you can simply call them *equivalent*.

> **Equivalent** *adjective*
>   Equal in value, amount, function, meaning, etc.
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equivalent)